# PDEs: Boundary term in the weak variational form of the 2D heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-element-method

I am looking at a [tutorial](http://hplgit.github.io/fenics-tutorial/pub/html/._ftut1008.html#ch:fundamentals:diffusion) on the Fenics software library for solving PDEs with finite elements. I have a question about the handling of the boundary term when we find the weak form for the 2D heat equation. My confusion is that the boundary term would drop out when the boundary integral is equal to zero, but in the tutorial the boundary integral is ignored by does not seem to integrate to zero. So I am wondering if this is an error in the tutorial or if I am missing something in the math?

The statement of the problem is:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla^2 u + f, \quad  \text{in } \Omega
$$
$$
u = u_D \text{ on } \partial\Omega
$$
$$
u = u_0 \text{ at } t = 0
$$
$$
u_D = 1 + x^2 + \alpha y^2 + \beta t
$$

We can discretize in time using finite differences, and then solve for the weak form as follows.

$$
\int_\Omega u^{n+1}v dV - \int_\Omega u^nv dV - \int_\Omega \Delta t \nabla^2 u^{n+1}v dV - \int_\Omega \Delta t f^{n+1}v dV = 0
$$

Now of course we would use the divergence theorem to reduce the order of the Laplacian term and get the following result. In the equation below, $dV, ds$ refer to the volume integral and surface(boundary) integral respectively.

$$
\int_\Omega u^{n+1}v dV - \int_\Omega u^nv dV - \int_{\partial \Omega} \Delta t v \frac{du}{dn}ds + \int_\Omega \Delta t \nabla u^{n+1}v dV  - \int_\Omega \Delta t f^{n+1}v dV = 0
$$

So in this setup--my own derivation, that boundary term $\partial \Omega$ would disappear if the integral over the boundary is equal to zero. However, in the problem setup above, the value of $u = u_D$ on the boundary, and in the tutorial, $u_D = 1 + x^2 + \alpha*y^2 + \beta*t$.

So in tutorial itself, the weak form is missing that boundary term. My assumption is that the authors believe that term integrated to zero. Here is the actual description of the weak form from the tutorial. *I included the $n+1$ superscript as that was omitted in the original tutorial text.*

$$
\int_\Omega u^{n+1}v + \Delta t \nabla u^{n+1}\nabla v -(u^n + \Delta t f^{n+1})v dx = 0
$$

I am just wondering why the boundary term over $\partial \Omega$ seems to have disappeared?

Note, I can ask this question on the Fenics forum, however I figured that this was more a math question than a specific coding problem. I imagine that the tutorial is correct and that I am missing something in the math, but I was not sure what I am missing, haha.

Hence I would appreciate it if someone can just tell me why that boundary term disappears, given that the boundary function does not seem to integrate to zero at each time step.

Comment: I think that this is just a mistake in the description of the variational formulation of the problem. They include the boundary condition $u_D$ it the implementation example that is on the page you linked. Do you know how to treat the non-zero Dirichlet b.c. in general or is this question only on the tutorial page?

Comment: @Korf thanks for the response. Hmm, I might not understand how to treat a non-zero Dirichlet boundary condition? So if the boundary integral is non-zero, then I imagine that the $v$ variable in that boundary would not be zero, and so that integral would have some value. So I would then add that value to the right hand side of the equation, and then solve the linear system. So in terms of the Fenics code, this would be like `f*v*dt*dx + v*diff(u,c)*dt*ds`. I am not sure how to implement the derivative $\frac{du}{dn}$ with respect to the normal direction in Fenics.

Comment: @Korf Okay, I think I am making some progress. I was looking at this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyKDc5hmBIs . I need to make sure I understand the math versus the code. So for a non-zero dirichlet bc, seems like the basis functions get updated with these values, and the interior of the boundary condition is homogeneous--something to that effect. So in the Fenics code, creating that `expression` will somehow update the basis to reflect this adjustment? I probably just need to go over it a few times to understand it.

Comment: @Korf Okay, I think I get it now. So basically the galerkin condition requires that the dirichlet condition has to be 0 on the boundary. So if you can specify the value of the function on the boundary points, then you can adjust the definition of the function space to meet the galerkin condition. The simple answer is that in the Fenics code they define the value of the function along the boundary in the `Expression`, and that allows Fenics to solve the problem.